# Why does a request repeat indefinitely in Firefox if it timed out in http.Server?

Tags: http, go, firefox, server, timeout

I'm setting up a simple server with timeouts in golang. When running a handler that takes longer than the timeout, the request repeats indefinitely if I request it with Firefox. However, if I use Postman or curl, the reuqest does not get repeated. I want to prevent a repeat-loop in browsers.

I have tried to close the request body manually or to check if the context was cancelled, however none of these methods works.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer r.Body.Close()
        fmt.Printf("Hello, you've requested: %s\n", r.URL.Path)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, you've requested: %s\n", r.URL.Path)
    })
    s := http.Server{
        Addr:         ":8080",
        Handler:      http.DefaultServeMux,
        ReadTimeout:  1 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
    }
    s.ListenAndServe()
}
```

I expected the handler to exit and not repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my understanding the issue you are facing is that the server timeouts are abruptly closing the underlying tcp conn without writing a proper http response, meanwhile, when firefox detects a conn closed abruptly it appears that it decides to retry N times, probably because it assumes that it encounters connectivity issues.

I believe the solution is to use an [http.Handler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) that controls the handler processing duration and return a proper HTTP response when the timeout expired.

The server timeouts should be longer and be used to prevent abnormal client behaviors and not the handlers slowness.

The standard HTTP package provides a [TimeoutHandler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#TimeoutHandler) function for that purpose.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    slowHandler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer r.Body.Close()
        fmt.Printf("Hello, you've requested: %s\n", r.URL.Path)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, you've requested: %s\n", r.URL.Path)
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/", slowHandler)

    var handler http.Handler = http.DefaultServeMux
    handler = http.TimeoutHandler(handler, time.Second, "processing timeout")

    s := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8080",
        Handler: handler,
        // ReadTimeout:  1 * time.Second,
        // WriteTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
    }
    s.ListenAndServe()
}
```